# "Chapter" not appearing in title

Tags: fonts, chapters

I am using the report class to submit my thesis. Since my university wants the word 'chapter' to be in a different font, and the title of the chapter to be in a different format, I made some changes. The problem is that, the word chapter is not appearing because of the modifications I made. Is there any way I could still get the word chapter to appear with the this format?

Here's the code

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[top=1.0in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\@startsection{chapter}{{Chapter} 1}{\z@}
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}
    {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{title}

\end{document}
```

I want this:

> Chapter 1 Title

but I'm getting that:

> 1 Title

Comment: I think you mean "different format" rather than "different font".

Comment: Yes, that's want I meant. Sorry!! my bad

Comment: I added the extra {Chapter} to see if it works, but as expected I got an error

Comment: @user1556826 I updated my answer with an option without additional packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To easily make modifications to the sectional unit headings, you can use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[top=1.0in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}{2.3ex plus.2ex}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Title}
Test text

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to use additional packages, you need to redefine the internal commands `\@makechapterhead` (for numbered chapters) and `\@makeschapterhead` (for unnumbered chapters), The code below contains the redefinitions needed to obtain the result you required:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[top=1.0in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vskip-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \LARGE\bfseries%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \@chapapp\space \thechapter\hspace{10pt}
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    #1\par\nobreak
     \vskip2.3ex \@plus.2ex
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vskip-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE\bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip2.3ex \@plus.2ex
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Title}
Test text

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used the package, and works like a charm. Thank You!!